# Laravel scout with elasticsearch - slow response

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, laravel-scout

this is my scenario:

I'm working on an application based on [Laravel 5.5](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5) that uses [Scout](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scout) and the [ElasticSearch Driver](https://github.com/babenkoivan/scout-elasticsearch-driver) to perform researches. Laravel app is running using the built-in server (php artisan serve).

My [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/) cluster is running on [docker](https://www.docker.com/) using [Laradock environment](http://laradock.io/).
I have an index that contains items like this:

```
{
                "_index": "artworks",
                "_type": "artworks",
                "_id": "575",
                "_score": 9.206466,
                "_source": {
                    "fields": [
                        {
                            "name": "artwork_name",
                            "value": "Earl Mills",
                            "language": "it"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "artwork_category",
                            "value": "Torp-Towne"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "technique",
                            "value": "neque",
                            "language": "it"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "subdivision",
                            "value": "facere",
                            "language": "it"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "stamp",
                            "value": "Manuela Gulgowski"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "cataloguer",
                            "value": "Cristal Lesch"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "alt_dimensioni",
                            "value": "Sunt molestiae eligendi et sed doloremque dolor. Debitis provident saepe deleniti. Aperiam et sint quo vel repudiandae tempora dicta qui."
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "larg_dimensioni",
                            "value": "Et odit qui libero. Eaque molestiae itaque et sed enim et. Nihil quod ea odio distinctio. Voluptate tempore sit ad rerum."
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "prof_dimensioni",
                            "value": "Sed pariatur nihil quia quia dolorum illo. Quaerat est sed dolore et. Ab est possimus hic cum repudiandae vero qui. Quo sunt molestiae fugit perspiciatis dolores fugit."
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Cartella_Serie",
                            "value": "Blanditiis incidunt quam dolor sunt. Labore voluptatem vero explicabo at molestiae eaque. Est ut incidunt voluptatibus ea impedit quos. Aspernatur dolorem unde vel ea."
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Tiratura_Esemplare",
                            "value": "Omnis quis non sed et non est. Nobis et sit explicabo praesentium. Ut eveniet tempora ratione quae. Odit qui eum facilis odit nihil officiis."
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Tiratura_Complessiva",
                            "value": "Fugit occaecati molestiae pariatur repellat mollitia. Eveniet iste quisquam et facilis. Iste accusantium magni quod magni architecto tempore quae. Beatae delectus sequi quibusdam et."
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Firmato",
                            "value": "Provident quidem quam ut et quis. Consequuntur unde nesciunt eligendi asperiores. Nulla et voluptate ut dignissimos autem asperiores incidunt."
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Titolo_per_ordinamento",
                            "value": "Eligendi consequatur odio reprehenderit quibusdam voluptatem. Veniam commodi necessitatibus dolorum dolorem voluptatum eveniet nobis. Optio dolores aspernatur odio non."
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Note_Storico_Artistiche",
                            "value": "Sit a animi expedita dolore quos qui ea. Consectetur dignissimos aut natus nam animi. Aut vitae alias molestias. Cupiditate molestiae dolores dolorem sint dolores.",
                            "language": "en"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Note_Storico_Artistiche",
                            "value": "Eos optio aut explicabo delectus. Est nihil non id autem. Pariatur ea in eum odio.",
                            "language": "it"
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

This index contains about 1000 items like the previous.
I'm testing the performance with a query like this:

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            [
               {
                  "match":{
                     "fields.value":"Manuela Gulgowski"
                  }
               }
            ]
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Performance result directly invoking elasticsearch instance with POST method:
**http://localhost:9200/artworks/_search?pretty=true --> ~50ms**

Performance result invoking my app:
**http://localhost:8000/api/v1/artworks/search?query=Manuela Gulgowski --> ~3500ms**

Both methods returns 10 elements a page.

My method is very simple:

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $query = $request->get("query");
        $artworks = Artwork::search($query)->paginate(10);
        return $this->sendResponse(new ArtworkCollectionResource($artworks));
    }
```

**Does somebody know if I'm missing something or in which way can I increase the performance?**
I perfectly understand that using my app api I cannot obtain a 50ms response, but I'm expecting that it will respond, at least, in ~600-700ms.

**Update** 
After a lot of test I've found that my app respond sometimes in ~900ms, other times in ~3500ms and this difference of latency is caused by paginate in Scout driver.

```
$results = Collection::make($engine->map(
            $rawResults = $engine->paginate($this, $perPage, $page), $this->model
        ));
```

I'm gonna investigate further.

Comment: Use xdebug's profiler to locate the issue.

Comment: You are testing on development hardware? Try installing everything on *production* grade hardware on DO it will cost you 1-10 bucks (for the test) but you will see that development != staging / production grade. I have high end Mac from 2014 and staging grade server beats the mac even with less RAM and with less cores in the task of building docker images. Good Luck!

Comment: Hi. I have the same issue where my ES result is 10ms but when I run it through Laravel API, it is around 800ms. Did you figure out the issue?